# What do i do after getting the token?

Tags: active-directory, wif, single-sign-on, adfs, sts-securitytokenservice

Here's the situation and what should i do now

- I have put CustomSTS as default selection in Home realm discovery page ( already configured the Custom STS as Claims Provider Trust )
- Any relying party added to ADFS 2.0 will now come back to Custom STS for the Single Sign On
- For custom authentication store i use the CustomSTS for Active Directory i tried through code from the link http://msinnovations.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/some-tips-on-active-federation-with-adfs-2-0/

and it worked great, I got the token. But now what, how do i set the Single Sign On cookie that ADFS 2.0 sets `FedAuth`,`FedAuth1`

Comment: Just to clarify - you now have a token in the relying party application and want to set a session cookie?

Comment: @leastprivilege hmm nope. I have a token from the ADFS, what do i do next, how do i set the Single Sign On cookie that ADFS sets if i had done these extra stuff

Comment: "I have a token from the ADFS" - where is that code physically running?

Comment: @leastprivilege thanks for getting back, the code is running in the customized ADFS `FormsSignIn.aspx` page, that has been modified to authenticate against SQL for authentication but also authenticates against ADDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ultimately need to call SignIn on the base class passing in either a token or a username/password of an AD account. That's all you can do.